# No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_columnWeight' in package 'android'

Tags: android, resources, package

Error:(25) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_columnWeight' in package 'android'....

i am not able to update it in my xml ..it arose when i was working with grid layout ..

```
 <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_columnWeight="0"
        />
   </GridLayout>
```

Comment: Is it from support librarY?

Comment: problem may be you android support library, use 21 or above

Comment: Please show the whole .xml file. Check your ` xmlns:android` attribute

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use `GridLayout` with `columnWeight` property the best way is to use v7 support version.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        app:layout_columnWeight="0"
        />
   </GridLayout>
```

Remember that if you want to use this v7.widget.GridLayout you must import this library adding `compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1'` to gradle

Answer (score 3):

`weight` is not supported by GridLayout until API 21. If you want it to be supported, you might want to use GridLayout from support library v7. Or switch to GridView.